# Heroku db:pull db:push Taps Load Error sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, heroku, rubygems

Trying to push or pull heroku's db by doing this:

```
heroku db:pull OR heroku db:push
```

And I got the next output

```
!    Taps Load Error: no such file to load -- sqlite3
!    You may need to install or update the taps gem to use db commands.
!    On most systems this will be:
!    
!    sudo gem install taps
```

Comment: Not an answer, but: Sooner or later, using SQLite in testing and PostgreSQL in production will bite you. I strongly recommend that you switch to running a local PostgreSQL for testing if you will be runnning on PostgreSQL in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. The first one is by adding in your project's gem file the next line (doesn't matter if you're using postgres db)

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

And the other solution is to view the source code of the `taps` gem at `path/to/taps/lib/taps` and remove from the file `cli.rb` the line 10:

```
require 'sqlite3'
```